# PHP/Joomla When to use references

Tags: php, joomla, pass-by-reference

i am reading http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_3_-_Using_the_Database

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
```

when do i need to use references? i tried the same thing without reference and it works. i thought objects are passed by reference (probably assignment also)? if i assign by "copy" will there be any difference? maybe drop in performance? and maybe i dont assign to the correct object (as i assigned to a copy of it)?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to assign by reference. The issue is that Joomla 1.5 is designed to work with both PHP 4 and 5. Joomla 1.6 is designed to be PHP 5 only, so there's a good chance that this will go away later.

So yes, if it works for you without assigning by reference, you can leave it that way.

And if you'd like to read more (probably far more than you wanted to know) about references in PHP, I'd highly recommend this article: http://blog.libssh2.org/index.php?/archives/51-Youre-being-lied-to..html